# Error app crud Angular

Tags: angular, crud

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con el siguiente error? Soy nuevo en Angular.

> Unexpected directive 'NgForm' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: Sin el código es complicado que podamos orientarte; sin embargo, al parecer te hace falta agregar una referencia a tu `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular no reconce esa directiva ya que probablemente no has importado 'FormsModule' en tu AppModule.

```js
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: gracias,ya importe pero no logro que se quite ese error,ya subire el codigo para ver si talvez es otro error.